# How to automatically add the node to parent group in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Hii i am relatively new to drupal 8 , i have a group type called news , i want the functionality when ever a new basic page is created it should attach to parent group news ,with out doing the step 'relate existing entity to group' , is there any module for that ?

Comment: Is your "group" a content type? Why not use a taxonomy?

Comment: not it is not content type, it is group